# php echo page title in foreign characters

Tags: php, character, echo, title

I want to echo page title from database value.

```
<title><?php echo $data['art_title'] ?></title>
```

But that language is Chinese. Title is not showing correctly. It's look like this now.

[image]

how to fix this problem? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
$sql = 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8';
```

here is full code

```
<?php
// MySQl connection 
$db = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password'); 

// Select the database 
mysql_select_db('db',$db); 

$sql = 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db);

// SQL query
$sql = "SELECT art_title, art_meta FROM article WHERE art_id=".$_GET['art_id']; 

// Send the query
$req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error()); 

$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($req);

?>

<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $data['art_meta']; ?>" />
<title><?php echo $data['art_title']; ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already are doing things right (writing both string in UTF-8) the problem can be Chrome/Firefox tryiing to use a font that is not unicode aware for the titles (?)... if thats the case, theres nothing you can do (report it?)

Just in case, make sure your page is correctly encoded (text in utf8, with the page declared in utf8).

**UPDATE**:

You could be hitting a OS/Browser bug:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90752

Comment: im using <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Then you must make sure these strings are in utf8 too.

Comment: yes strings are in utf8, same title echo in the content. it's showing correctly.

Comment: Sassi, is the `<meta>` tag in the HTML above or below the `<title>` tag? While browsers should be able to handle either order, try putting `<meta>` first.

Answer (score 0):

When you saving your page choose its endoding `utf-8` or another chinese supported encoding.